# Add extra IF to SUMIFS

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table that is populated from a sql database. It has the following fields.

```
Ticket  DateTimeOpened  DateTimeClosed  Status  Author  Caller  AssignedTo  ClosedBy    TechTime    Total Hours
```

What I am trying to do is a SUMIFS (or whatever is the proper way) of a date range but only if the AssignedTo does not equal a certain person.

So I know that the below works as standardly. But I am not sure on how to add in an extra IF so if G != "Tom Smith" to not add that into the total.

```
=SUMIFS(SQLDump!K:K,SQLDump!C:C,">=1/1/11",SQLDump!C:C,"<=12/31/11")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another condition to `SUMIFS` like this

```
=SUMIFS(SQLDump!K:K, SQLDump!C:C,">=1/1/11", SQLDump!C:C,"<=12/31/11", **SQLDump!G:G,  "<>Tom Smith"**)
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was convined I had to reinvent the wheel to pull this off.